# Porque no me funciona la función recursiva? necesito que vuelva a entrar al condicional llamandose a ella misma

Tags: javascript

```
function calculo(str,primero){

    if(primero===undefined){
        var primero=false;
        var strOut="";
        strOut+=str.slice(0,2);
        str=str.substr(2, str.length);
        calculo(str,primero);
    }else if(str.length!==0){
        strOut+="*"+str.slice(0,2);
    }
    return strOut;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calculo("Prueba de recusrsividad");
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado te devuelve actualmente la llamada a la función? ¿qué resultado esperas que devuelva?

Comment: Solo "Pr" y devería devolverme "Pr*ue" ya tiene que volver a entrar al condicional

Comment: Intenta cambiar la llamada recursiva por: `strOut += calculo(str, primero);`. Creo que con eso debiera funcionar como esperas.

Comment: cuidado también con el `var primero = false;` ya que estás iniciando una variable que ya existe con el mismo nombre, simplemente quita el `var`

Comment: Gracias, aunque sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que hay varias cosas en tu código que te sobran. Entiendo que quieres sacar el `string` separado cada dos caracteres por un `*`:

1. Ya que tienes el parámetro `primero` recurre a él y no juegues con `undefined`
2. En el segundo `else` no estabas llamando a `calculo()` por lo que tu recursividad terminaba ahí. Además en ese punto `strOut` es `undefined`.

Te dejo aquí tu código ligeramente modificado

```js
var strOut="";
var primero;
function calculo(str,primero){ 
 if(primero){
     strOut+=str.slice(0,2);
 }
 else{
     strOut+="*"+str.slice(0,2);
 }
     str=str.substr(2, str.length);
  if(str.length>0){
     calculo(str,false); 
  }
    return strOut;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calculo("Prueba de recusrsividad",true);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema si era eso de que la variable no estaba definida, no sabia que las variables tenías que definirlas afuera cuando utilizabas la recursividad, en cuando a la variable "primero" como indefinida lo que quiero es que no tengas que ponerla en tu primera llamada a la función y no encontré otra forma

Comment: ¿Y por qué quieres no tener que ponerla? Ten en cuenta el sentido de esa variable. Con ella le dices si es la primera llamada o no (true o false) y ya está. En cuanto a las variables. Piensa que estás volviendo a llamar a la función por lo que hay que tener cuidado con el valor de cada una.